# Problems that reduce to or are abstracted by the learning juntas problem

Tags: lg.learning, boolean-functions

What problems are either abstracted by or reduce to the learning juntas problem?

(An example of a real-world problem *abstracted by* the learning juntas problem is the [Identification of genetic loci participating in disease penetrance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14614241).)

Bonus points if the total number of attributes is very large, the number of juntas is small, and the problem permits active queries.

I'm asking because I have reason to believe that [this algorithm](http://blog.hackingevolution.net/2013/09/03/evolving-juntas/), or one like it, may be of service.